# Creating a MYSQL table in a Docker container with a SQL file

Tags: mysql, docker

I have created a MySQL docker container with

```
sudo docker run -d --name db-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword -e MYSQL_DATABASE=DB mysql
```

I have *schema.sql* to create the schema

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `DB`;
CREATE DATABASE `DB`;
USE `DB`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Occurrences`;
CREATE TABLE `Occurrences` (
  `IdOccurrence` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Min_probability` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdOccurrence`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `Occurrences` VALUES (1,'Frequent',20),(2,'Probable',10),(5,'Possible',1),(6,'Rare',0.1),(7,'Remote',0);
```

And try to import it (in Ubuntu 18.04) with

```
sudo docker exec db-mysql mysql -uroot -pmypassword DB < schema.sql
```

However, I get this warning

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

But the database DB remains empty.

Where is my error?

Comment: Just to give another idea: Most programming languages have some sort of library to execute database migrations. If this mysql docker is part of another application, you _may_ consider moving the migration one level up.

Comment: @maio290 Do you know where can I find how to migrate with mysql.connector in Python?

Comment: I am mostly on the Java and php side of development, so unfortunately, no.

Comment: Does it work without the first 3 lines in schema.sql?

Comment: @JonathanClark No

Comment: If you do `sudo docker exec db-mysql mysql -uroot -p` do you connect and able to run sql commands from there such as `show databases;`?

Comment: You might need `-h 127.0.0.1` `-p 3306` for host and port if they're different to default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) for the docker image you can initialize a container with a sql script:

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL
>   dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
>   data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
>   by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

So if you start your container with the following it should startup with your schema:

```
sudo docker run -d --name db-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword -e MYSQL_DATABASE=DB -v $PWD/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql mysql
```